# Stopping Execution Of A Parent Function From Child In R

Tags: r, function, break

I'm using the `stop` function in R to make some troubleshooting measures. For example throwing an error when data was input wrong. I want a general function that I can call to do this checking, that I can then call in several different points of the parent code. I can throw an error just fine, however, I've noticed that the parent function keeps executing after the error is thrown and only my "error function" if you will stops executing. Is there a way to make R stop executing globally when an error from `stop` occurs?

Thank you.

A coded example of my issue:

```
StopCode <- function() {

  try(if(TRUE) stop("This try/if statement should stop the code from executing."))

}

StopCode() # This function should stop the code!

print("I should not see this statement if the try/if statement stopped the code in the way I desired.")
```

Console:

```
Error in try(if (TRUE) stop("This try/if statement should stop the code from executing.")) : 
  This try/if statement should stop the code from executing.
[1] "I should not see this statement if the try/if statement stopped the code in the way I desired."
```

The desired result should be that the StopCode function entirely stops the code instead of just the execution of the function. When you source this code, it stops the function, gives a warning and then proceeds to run the print function. I want that to not happen and for the stop in the function to kill the execution globally.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I have encountered this behaviour when functions encounter an error as part of a script, where the top level is not a function, but never inside a function itself. My understanding is that stop should return you to the top level browser, halting the execution of all functions in the call stack.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I added an example of what I am doing and the functionality I am not getting. I want the function to stop execution globally, not just within the function.

Comment: If you don’t want the caller to continue executing, don’t wrap the call inside `try`! You’re explicitly telling R *not* to stop (which would otherwise be the default behaviour).

Comment: Ah, should have realized that! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `stop` does exactly what you want it to do: it breaks out of every running function until it is at the top level — and, if the script is running non-interactively, it then stops the script.

However, in the code you’ve posted you explicitly tell R *not* to stop executing the calling function, by trapping the error via `try`. It’s unclear why you are using `try` here, since its only purpose is to prevent the behaviour that you seem to want.

The solution is simply to remove `try` from your code. Alternatively, you may want to trap the error, handle it, and then re-throw it:

```
result = try(‹some operation that may fail›)
if (inherits(result, 'try-error')) {
    ‹handle error›
    # Re-throw error:
    stop(attr(result, 'condition'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to set options(error = ) to some function of your choosing. I'll paste the docs here ?options:

```
error:
either a function or an expression governing the handling of non-catastrophic
errors such as those generated by stop as well as by signals and internally
detected errors. If the option is a function, a call to that function, with
no arguments, is generated as the expression. The default value is NULL: see
stop for the behaviour in that case. The functions dump.frames and recover
provide alternatives that allow post-mortem debugging. Note that these need 
to specified as e.g. options(error = utils::recover) in startup files such
as ‘.Rprofile’.
```

Comment: The default option already does the correct thing for OP’s desired behaviour, changing it won’t help.

Comment: Well, not necessarily, e.g., options(error = function(...) browser()). That way, you don't hit the next line until some user input is collected. Additionally, I'm inferring what the OP wants to do. Or, if you want to be more aggressive: options(error = function(...) quit(save = 'no').

Comment: Right, what I meant was: R already does the right thing, the OP *should not* change the option to achieve what they want, they should fix their code instead.